# Android RelativeLayout placing 2 views next to eachother one view is variable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking at placing 2 views next to each other.
1 `View` has a `fixed width` while the other should take up the rest of the space (variable).

I have currently set the layout with the `fixed width view` with the `alignParentRight="true"` that is fine however it overlaps the variable width view.

I would like them to be side-by-side. Maybe a `Horizontal LinearLayout` is best for this task?

What I have currently is:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Selector
    android:id="@+id/side_selector"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

Comment: use linearlayout with layout_weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use LinearLayout with layou_weigth, just like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Selector
        android:id="@+id/side_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `RelativeLayout`, try aligning the Selector View to the right of ListView.

`layout_toRightOf="@id/id"`

Comment: I tried that, but I wanted the variable width `match_parent` view to fill the rest of the space. With this method the view on the right is not shown.